# How to get what channel users is watching on Smart TV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I want to know what channel users is viewing using my apps, to display related real-time information. 
Does it support and allow us to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Window plugin from SEF plugin API. There is [GetCurrentChannel_Name](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00014/GetCurrentChannel_Name.html) function to get channel name.
You can also use [TV plugin](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00014/sef_plugin_tv.html) - there is information about program.